# "Can't get attribute" with pickle.load

Tags: pycharm, attributeerror

If I try to open and read a pickle file in a shell, I got the following error:

```
with open("labeled_data_test.pkl","rb") as fp:
----> 2     data = pickle.load(fp)
      3

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'LabeledData' on <module '__main__'
```

Same if i run the test-file for my original file in pycharm.

```
    correct = pickle.load(fp)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'LabeledData' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.4\\helpers\\pycharm\\_jb_unittest_runner.py'>
```

I found a related question with the same error - they mentioned to import everything in the testfile, which I did with `from file import *` and I also tried `from file import LabeledData`. Both didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does it work when executed from the terminal? Try to disable "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" option in PyCharm run configuration used to launch the script.

Comment: No, same issue from the terminal. I copied now the complete class into the file instead of "simply" importing it. That helped. Weird. But worked.